# Connect to a bluetooth device programmatically objective c

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth

Is it possible to programmatically connect to a bluetooth device. So, without having the user to open the Bluetooth settings and select the device they need to connect to. Note: The device it needs to connect to will always have the same device name.

Comment: In iOS or Mac OS ? In iOS, you can't if not paired before...

Comment: David: Did you get any solution for the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you use Core Bluetooth to discover all devices that are discoverable. Then if it matches a name etc then connect to it.

I made a wrapper around Apple's Core Bluetooth framework to make it easier to do these things.

https://github.com/steprescott/SCPCoreBluetoothManager

Comment: hi, are you here? I download your project and got this issue:
https://postimg.org/image/fy61tufs3/
how can i solve it? Thanks you